# Negative X or Y obtained from PdfBox while extracting text position

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to extract all text in a pdf along with their coordinates.
I am using **Apache PDFBox 2.0.8** and following the sample program [DrawPrintTextLocations](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/DrawPrintTextLocations.java?view=markup) .

It seems to work mostly, but for certain pdf-s i **get negative values for the x and y coordinates of the bounding boxes**. Refer this [pdf file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13Ya0dr88zRL6twVHZRSni5pbAT3u3MEo) for example.

My app assumes the coordinate system as a normal pdf (x goes from left to right an y goes top to bottom). so these are throwing my computations off.

Below is the relevant piece of code.

```
import org.apache.fontbox.util.BoundingBox;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType3Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation.PDThreadBead;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This is an example on how to get some x/y coordinates of text and to show them in a rendered
 * image.
 *
 * @author Ben Litchfield
 * @author Tilman Hausherr
 */
public class DrawPrintTextLocations extends PDFTextStripper {
    private AffineTransform flipAT;
    private AffineTransform rotateAT;
    private AffineTransform transAT;

    private final float DPI = 200.0f;
    private final double PT2PX = DPI / 72.0;
    private final AffineTransform dpiAT = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(PT2PX, PT2PX);

    private final String filename;
    static final int SCALE = 1;
    private Graphics2D g2d;
    private final PDDocument document;

    /**
     * Instantiate a new PDFTextStripper object.
     *
     * @param document
     * @param filename
     * @throws IOException If there is an error loading the properties.
     */
    public DrawPrintTextLocations(PDDocument document, String filename) throws IOException {
        this.document = document;
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    /**
     * This will print the documents data.
     *
     * @param args The command line arguments.
     * @throws IOException If there is an error parsing the document.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String pdfLoc = "/debug/pdfbox/p2_VS008PI.pdf";

        if (args.length == 1) {
            pdfLoc = args[0];
        }

        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfLoc))) {
            DrawPrintTextLocations stripper = new DrawPrintTextLocations(document, pdfLoc);
            stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

            for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
                stripper.stripPage(page);
            }
        }
    }

    private void stripPage(int page) throws IOException {
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
        BufferedImage image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, DPI);

        PDPage pdPage = document.getPage(page);
        PDRectangle cropBox = pdPage.getCropBox();

        // flip y-axis
        flipAT = new AffineTransform();
        flipAT.translate(0, pdPage.getBBox().getHeight());
        flipAT.scale(1, -1);

        // page may be rotated
        rotateAT = new AffineTransform();
        int rotation = pdPage.getRotation();
        if (rotation != 0) {
            PDRectangle mediaBox = pdPage.getMediaBox();
            switch (rotation) {
                case 90:
                    rotateAT.translate(mediaBox.getHeight(), 0);
                    break;
                case 270:
                    rotateAT.translate(0, mediaBox.getWidth());
                    break;
                case 180:
                    rotateAT.translate(mediaBox.getWidth(), mediaBox.getHeight());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            rotateAT.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotation));
        }

        // cropbox
        transAT = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-cropBox.getLowerLeftX(), cropBox.getLowerLeftY());

        g2d = image.createGraphics();
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.1f));
        g2d.scale(SCALE, SCALE);

        setStartPage(page + 1);
        setEndPage(page + 1);

        Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
        writeText(document, dummy);

        g2d.dispose();

        String imageFilename = filename;
        int pt = imageFilename.lastIndexOf('.');
        imageFilename = imageFilename.substring(0, pt) + "-marked-" + (page + 1) + ".png";
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(imageFilename));
    }

    /**
     * Override the default functionality of PDFTextStripper.
     */
    @Override
    protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {

        for (TextPosition text : textPositions) {

            AffineTransform at = text.getTextMatrix().createAffineTransform();
            PDFont font = text.getFont();

            BoundingBox bbox = font.getBoundingBox();

            float xadvance = font.getWidth(text.getCharacterCodes()[0]); // todo: should iterate all chars
            Rectangle2D.Float rect1 = new Rectangle2D.Float(0, bbox.getLowerLeftY(), xadvance, bbox.getHeight());

            if (font instanceof PDType3Font) {
                at.concatenate(font.getFontMatrix().createAffineTransform());
            } else {
                at.scale(1 / 1000f, 1 / 1000f);
            }

            Shape s1 = at.createTransformedShape(rect1);
            s1 = flipAT.createTransformedShape(s1);
            s1 = rotateAT.createTransformedShape(s1);
            s1 = dpiAT.createTransformedShape(s1);

            g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
            g2d.draw(s1);

            Rectangle bounds = s1.getBounds();
            if (bounds.getX() < 0 || bounds.getY() < 0) {
                // THIS is where things go wrong
                // i need these coordinates to be +ve
                System.out.println(bounds.toString());
                System.out.println(rect1.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is some snippet of the output from the first page of the above pdf.

> SECTION 10 – INSURANCE & OTHER FINANCIAL RESOURCES
>   java.awt.Rectangle[x=-3237,y=40,width=19,height=43]
>   java.awt.Rectangle[x=-3216,y=40,width=20,height=43]
>   java.awt.Rectangle[x=-3194,y=40,width=23,height=43]
>   java.awt.Rectangle[x=-3170,y=40,width=22,height=43]

Comment: I suspect that this is outside of the cropbox. Text extraction gets all. (Note that SECTION 10 is visible on page 5. This may be one of these PDFs where one page is only a visible subset of a larger thing)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  any way i can verify that for sure ?
I tried to modify your sample near [line 253](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/DrawPrintTextLocations.java?view=markup#l253) to draw the crop box as well, it seems indeed much smaller. 

this is what i used ...
        Shape s = cropBox.toGeneralPath().createTransformedShape(transAT);
        s = flipAT.createTransformedShape(s);
        s = rotateAT.createTransformedShape(s);

Comment: call `pdPage.setCropBox(pdPage.getMediaBox());` for each page and save, then display this file.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr you seem to be correct. Though my previous attempt of viewing the cropbox was incorrect. Following your advice of setting the crop box to the media box, actually changed the whole on screen appearance of the pdf, now i got 3 pages collated as one. This was the reason i reported "Section 10" on first page. Any suggestions to cleanly handle cases like these other than checking the coods of each text position ?

Comment: No, I don't have any.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr ok, can you formulate your original comment into an answer, so i can accept it. I guess it's reasonable enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters with negative coordinates are outside the cropbox (also characters with coordinates bigger than the cropbox height / width). See the cropbox as a cutout from something bigger. To see the whole thing, run this code

```
pdPage.setCropBox(pdPage.getMediaBox());
```

for each page of your PDF and then save and view it.

Per your comment

> Following your advice of setting the crop box to the media box, actually changed the whole on screen appearance of the pdf, now i got 3 pages collated as one.

This suggests that physically, this is a folded sheet that has 3 pages on each side. The online PDF displays this as 6 pages for easy viewing on a computer.